# Ubuntu freezes after drag and drop a file to nautilus window

Tags: gnome, 20.04, nautilus, 20.10

When I drag and drop any file from my desktop to nautilus window the whole system freezes and no shortcut and command works. and I can't do anything with it. only restart would fix the issue.

It is something similar to [this issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons/+bug/1898462)

and also [this one](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1710346)

is there any command or update for fixing this issue?

I just updated to Ubuntu 20.10 and I don't remember this issue on 20.04.

Answer (score 1):

hopefully, I find a solution for this. just paste this code to terminal and reboot.

> gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences use-experimental-views false

but it will disable drag and drop between nautilus and desktop which in ubuntu 20.04+ is disabled by default.

for those who have 20.10 version this will fix the issue.

Comment: I use unity desktop on 20.04, it worked like a charm :) thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Following your first link, there seems to be an unofficial update that you could try (and you might be able to help the developers test it). Otherwise, you could wait for an official update.

Comment: thanks for your response. I've tried this package https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons/20.04.0+git20200908-5~ubuntu20.10.0/+build/20719201/+files/gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons_20.04.0+git20200908-5~ubuntu20.10.0_all.deb and it didn't fix my issue. It seemed that this package was installed already. I also deleted and reinstalled it but nothing changed

Comment: I just commented here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/groovy/+source/gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons/+bug/1898462. I hope someone can fix this.